# Ассоциативные массивы в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть ли в PostgreSQL ассоциативные массивы?
Если есть, то как их объявлять и наполнять?

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую такой сущности как ассоциативный массив в Postgresql нет. Для хранения и обработки такой структуры можно использовать [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) или куда более старый `contrib` модуль [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). В сущности, это одно и то же, авторы обоих типов - одни и те же люди и существенная часть кода у этих типов общая.

`JSON` - просто `JSON`. Добавили в версии 9.2, с тех пор активно развивается и обрастает функционалом. Лучше использовать тип данных `JSONB` (добавлен в 9.4) вместо более старого `JSON` из-за возможности нормально индексировать `JSONB`.

```
create table kvtest (id serial primary key, arr JSONB);
insert into kvtest (arr) values('{"key1": 1}') returning id;
update kvtest set arr = arr || '{"key2": 1}'::jsonb where id=1;
```

`hstore` - куда более старый тип. По-умолчанию расширение отключено, требуется загрузить командой один раз для БД:

```
create extension hstore;
```

Ну а использование похоже, только синтаксис значений отличается:

```
create table kvtest2 (id serial primary key, arr hstore);
insert into kvtest2 (arr) values('key1 => 1') returning id;
update kvtest2 set arr = arr || 'key2=>2'::hstore where id=1;
```

Подробнее про имеющиеся функции для обработки и манипуляций смотрите в мануале к своей версии postgresql. В свежих версиях postgresql имеет смысл выбрать именно `JSONB`, с json обычно удобнее работать на приложении, чем через hstore.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы в реляционных БД были ассоциативные массивы как тип данных, то не было бы смысла изобретать нереляционные БД :) Практически в каждой субд есть костыли, с помощью которых можно реализовать что-то отдаленно напоминающее ассоциативный массив. В Oracle это, например, Nested Tables (Вложенные таблицы).

В чистом PostgreSQL есть возможность использовать лишь временные таблицы.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(id integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$declare
begin

CREATE TEMP TABLE vr_table (id integer,  value  varchar);

.... /*делаете что-то */

DROP TABLE vr_table;

return;
end;$BODY$
```

CREATE **TEMP** TABLE - TEMP указывает на то, что таблица временная.

Также, в ячейке можно хранить JSON и обращаться к нему по индексу, например так:

```
SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data ->> 'a' > '1';
```

Если есть возможность устанавливать плагины, то можно попробовать **hstore**:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html

Там реализован полноценный тип **Ключ-Значение**